How Does ElectronJs Determine Locale?
I am very curious on how does electron 21.1.0 detects an operating system locale given it provided no way to set it manually.
I had this bizzare case on one of the machine that was set as en-US on its region and language configuration but navigator.language always shows en-GB. I have checked the navigator.language on both Chrome (131) and Firefox (134.0b) in Windows 10 N LTSC version 1809 and they respected the region configuration.

How was the machine set to en-US while showing en-GB? Notice system language doesn't have to be browser language. Users can set their browser's language independently in the settings.

@PeterPointer afaik [tag:electron] no longer allows developer to set language. it will detect OS configured language automatically. thing is, it kinda bugged on this one which stumped me. its an old code which nobody touched for the past 2 years and it fell on my lap to fix.

So getLocale is a locale you haven't set? Can you post what getPreferredSystemLanguages outputs? Your locales directory has the en-US locale? Just asking to put that in the question, could help someone solve the issue.

@PeterPointer what a bummer, I read your questions after I uninstalled all of the language packs in the offending machine except en-US and solved the problem. that being said, given navigator.language gave en-GB most likely getLocale will give similar result.
